# Extjs context menu (right click) on a button

Tags: extjs

I would like to know how to put an Extjs Context Menu (Right Click) onto a button.

I have searched google but all I seem to get is how to put it onto a TreePanel. I have tried a similar approach to the TreePanel with buttons but with no luck.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The context menu is just floating menu, so just grab the context menu event and show the menu. Since the button doesn't have the contextmenu you can grab directly the htmlelement (or the Element wrapper) and listen to the contextmenu event

example:

```
contextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
  items: [{
    text: 'Edit',
    iconCls: 'edit',
    handler: edit
  }]
});

Ext.getCmp('your-button').getEl().on('contextmenu', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     contextMenu.show(Ext.getCmp('your-button').getEl());
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to put it on the contextMenu:function(){} which seemed to be causing me grief

Comment: Is it possible to position the menu to the same position as the right-click was made?

Comment: @kiltek i know this is old, had same issue, fixed like this `contextMenu.showAt(e.getXY());`